# How to use onDraw(Canvas) to obtain a bitmap snapshot of the WebView(Android)

Tags: android, webview, bitmap, android-canvas, snapshot

I used to use capturePicture() method to make a snapshot of my WebView.
This method was deprecated in API level 19.

The doc say that "Use onDraw(Canvas) to obtain a bitmap snapshot of the WebView", but I really don't know how it means.

Will you please teach me how to solve the problem?

Comment: just call webView.onDraw(canvas)

Comment: Thank you! But onDraw(canvas) is protected. I can`t just call it. And it returns nothing.

Comment: extend WebView and call it from there, use a Canvas created by new Canvas(Bitmap)

Comment: Like this? Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(),
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
  this.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));

Comment: I only capture a blank image...

Comment: what are dimensions of a Bitmap?

Comment: mWebView.getWidth() and mWebView.getHeight(), in fact i need mWebView.getWidth() and mWebView.getContentHeight()

Answer (score 4):

The following should work:

```
float scale = webView.getScale();
int webViewHeight = (int)(webView.getContentHeight() * scale);
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getWidth(), webViewHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
webView.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: Do you capture entire the webview or just things which are visible? I meant if the web content is long, can your method capture all the entire?

Comment: @lolyoshi `WebView.draw()` will indeed capture all the content, but I'm not sure if `WebView.getWidth()` will return the correct width for the content, I still have to check that for the app I'm working on.

Comment: Yes! Using getContentHeight() * getScale() does captures entire page not just a visible content.

Comment: On Android 6.0 it does NOT capture the entire view, only the visible part.

Comment: getScale() is deprecated

Comment: out of memory exception. can anyone help please. I just need to capture visible area. Also `getScale()` is deprecated