# Android best way to generate an image from a layout engine (justified text, box positioning, embed images...)

Tags: android, layout, webview, png

It's been three days I'm looking for (and test) libs which can perform a generation of an **image** from **textual content**. I develop an app on **Android** with the Augmented Reality [Metaio SDK](http://www.metaio.com/SDK/). To apply a texture with text and image embed, I **must** generate a PNG file. So I need a method :

- Compatible with *Android*
- On the Android *client* : not generating the PNG on a server
- With the *right way* like html/css, svg or Android layout for example : ie not having to make justify text and box positionning from scratch, I'm sure you understand why x)
- Which can perform a generation in external thread (ie without the user have to see the layout)

I tested a lot of solutions, but nothing works.

**Using WebView**

Some topics about this :

- [Generate bitmap from HTML in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633988/generate-bitmap-from-html-in-android)
- [How to use onDraw(Canvas) to obtain [...]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856832/how-to-use-ondrawcanvas-to-obtain-a-bitmap-snapshot-of-the-webviewandroid)
- [Convert HTML to image (any format) on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525311/convert-html-to-image-any-format-on-android)
- [Capturing android webview image and saving to png/jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351298/capturing-android-webview-image-and-saving-to-png-jpeg)
- [Which can replace capturePicture function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942623/which-can-replace-capturepicture-function)
- [Capture picture from WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538429/capture-picture-from-webview)

Ultimately, *onPageFinished* is not enough and we must implement :

```
webView.setPictureListener(new PictureListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture)
    {
        [...]
```

It works, but it's *deprecated* and the *WebView* must be visible if I want to generate a png, and it does not suit me.

**Using Android Layout**

Some topics about this :

- [How do I convert a RelativeLayout [...]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188737/how-do-i-convert-a-relativelayout-with-an-imageview-and-textview-to-a-png-image)
- [Converting a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android)
- [Android Problems Converting ViewGroup with Children into Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960753/android-problems-converting-viewgroup-with-children-into-bitmap)
- [convert view into bitmap [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264990/convert-view-into-bitmap)

Once again, I must have a *visible* View to generate a PNG from it.

**Using [svg-android](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/wiki/Tutorial)**

Some topics about this :

- [SVG to Bitmap at runtime Conversion in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201542/svg-to-bitmap-at-runtime-conversion-in-android)

It works, but there are only basic functions : *include text*, *image* or *data-uri image* **don't work**.

**Using [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)**

[SVG Rasterizer](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html) and [its use](http://massapi.com/class/pn/PNGTranscoder.html).

It works, but not on Android.

> Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeeded in using a WebView **without having to see the view**. I set the width to 0.1dp and switch *visible/invisible* quickly.

I use a **WebView** because the layout engine is more complete. **But warning** : as mentioned higher, the method *onNewPicture* is deprecated.

I implemented a class containing a **GenerationProcess** which perform all Thread treatments (on the **UI Thread** or on a **backgroud Thread**) and a **GenerationQueue** which perform a Thread ordering. So this class is **totally independent** and you can use it without having to think about the Thread you are.

With the **Android Layout engine**, we don't have to use all these Thread because there is no callback function like onPageFinished and onNewPicture : make your choice !

[Github Project - WebView2Img](https://github.com/hayj/WebView2Img)

You can take a look at :

- *./src* containing [the Activity example](https://github.com/hayj/WebView2Img/blob/master/src/com/example/webview2img/WebView2ImageView.java) and [the class Page](https://github.com/hayj/WebView2Img/blob/master/src/com/example/webview2img/Page.java)
- *./res/layout* containing [the layout example](https://github.com/hayj/WebView2Img/blob/master/res/layout/image_view.xml)
- *./assets* containing all html example

Then you can **extends Page** to manipulate the DOM (with [jdom](http://www.jdom.org/) for example) to dynamicaly set content and save the html file.

**EDIT :** [here](https://github.com/hayj/WebView2Img/blob/master/src/com/example/webview2img/AndroidPage.java) an example of extends Page with dom manipulation before generation